# How does double bond placement, in an alkene, affect the boiling point of the alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, boiling-point

Will having the double bond be closer to the middle of the molecule result in a higher or lower boiling point than that of an isomer with the double bond closer to one of the ends? Also, does the same relationship apply to alkynes?

Comment: Prediction of boiling and melting points are amongst the most difficult things to predict before hand. Don't worry too much about it. Most software, like ChemDraw, churn out ridiculous values. I don't how it makes such predictions.

Comment: Perhaps it could be done, even by feeling, if you focus on a pair of such isomers. For instance, I suspect that something more symmetric would have a higher BP. Check it out. For the rest see M. Farooq comment.

Comment: Perhaps chances for an educated guess being correct (say, with some $\Delta{}T \approx \pu{10 K}$) if one narrows the scope to simpler classes for some prior training.  E.g., otherwise non-branched alcohols, carboxylic acids with either odd or even number of carbon atoms.